# Array column positioning and non-stop do...while loop

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

This little program is supposed to only loop through the first column of the 2d array and see if i matches the user's input, so 10 or 15, but it only matches 10.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String numInput;
    String answer = "";
    String number[][] = {

            { "10", "20", "30" },

            { "15", "25", "35" }, };

    System.out.print("\n");

    do {

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                System.out.print("\t" + number[i][j] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println("\n");
        }

        boolean found = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                while (!found) {

                    System.out.print("\n\tEnter a Number : ");
```

Expected input 10 or 15

```
                    numInput = input.nextLine();

                    if (numInput.equals(number[i][0])) {

                        found = true;

                        System.out.print("\n\tNumber " + numInput + " found");

                        System.out.print(" on line " + i);

                        break;
                    }

                    System.out.print("\n\tNumber not found!\n");

                }

            }

        }

        // Do...while loop to ask user if thery want to ocntinue.

        do {

            System.out.print("\n\n\tContinue? Yes (y) or No (n) : ");

            answer = input.nextLine();
```

And this do...while loop to ask the user if they wanna continue is infinite wether the iput is Y,y or N,n.

```
        } while (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("N"));

        // while from Main Do Loop.

    } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

    System.out.print("\n\tDone!");
}
```

Comment: Literally any input by the user will be not equal to one of "Y" OR "N".

Comment: `!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("N")` is the same as `answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && answer.equalsIgnoreCase("N")` which is impossible

Comment: What's a possible solution then?

Comment: Write the condition you actually intend, rather than one which is impossible to meet.

Comment: Oh yeah! I get it. Thanks! How about the array positioning though?